# Import Android Context into a function file in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, android-context

I try to create a POST request with Android Volley but when I type `volleyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)`, this is a error "this is not defined in this context".
I know that I have this problem because my function can't resolve Android Context but I don't understand how to import the context in my file.
Here you have my project scheme:

[image]

and the error
[image]

The function is called in the "FormsAddAliments" file.

Thanks you !

Comment: don't EVER post code as print screen... `ProgressBar` need `Context`, so `Activity` in your case. pass it as an argument of your method

Comment: So something like ```sendFood(arg1, ...., this)``` when calling and in definition ```fun sendFoodToServer(args1: String, ..., formsAddAliments: FormsAddAliments )```
?

Comment: you singleton pattern for volley and control  progressbar or other view related things inside activity or fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "this is not defined in this context" is not referring to the abstract class `android.content.Context`, but rather the context of the code.

You are using `this` in a top level function in a file. There is no object that `this` can be a reference to, if you want it to be a top level function and have an object that `this` can reference, you will need to declare it as an extension function on the type that you want `this` to reference like `Context.sendFoodToServer(...)`. This should work, but it is likely violating some design principles to do it this way (usually passing a context around is a bad idea because it can lead to context leaking).

Comment: What's should be the correct answer to not violating design principles ?

Comment: This really depends, however, usually it would involve constructing the request queue where the context is readily available and pass the queue to where it is needed, in the case of the progress dialog, similar thing goes, you'd construct it in the fragment or activity, then provide some way to update the progress from a viewmodel or such using something like livedata. Statically holding a context object is generally a bad idea (leak), but passing it as a parameter or receiver of a function, isn't usually a leak.

Comment: That's what I did thx !